Resource path handling between REST Layer and Service Layer
What is a good way to handle "top-level" IDs in a Resource-oriented API path?
Consider a call to
GET /resourceA/12/resourceB/23

where A to B is a Parent-Child relationship and B has globally unique identifiers.
The REST Layer could simply do
return resourceBService.find(23);

But this completely ignores whether the user has "followed" the correct path, i.e. whether 23 is an actual child of 12.
So I think there are two options here:

The REST Layer always explicitly checks IDs in cases where they would go unnoticed.
Drawback: It could overload the REST Layer with too much application logic. Also sometimes the REST Layer cannot check everything, so some checks need to be performed in the Service Layer anyway. This seems to split responsibilities.

The Service Layer always demands all Parent IDs for context, since we are dealing with Parent-Child relationships. Uniqueness of the child's ID in the database is a technical detail that should not be taken for granted.
Drawback: I am modeling the Service Layer after a specific client (Resource-based). Maybe other clients don't need this approach at all and it would be cumbersome to use.


Is there a best practice?

do you mean this "REST Layer"? https://github.com/rs/rest-layer

You should probably review "Information Hiding" - especially Parnas 1971.

@Ewan No I'm just talking about the Controller Layer that is calling the Application Layer

@VoiceOfUnreason the problem is what constitutes "information hiding" depends on what design decision I make. if I decide to explicitly model the relationship as Parent-Child, then offering the method service.read(parentId, childId) does not violate encapsulation. if I decide the relationship is just an association, then service.read(id) is enough, as the model doesn't care about an arbitrary association inside the entity.


Uniqueness of the child's ID in the database is a technical detail
that should not be taken for granted

I think I would disagree with this. Its part of the domain design whether the children only have meaning when linked to a parent, or if they are entities in their own right.
eg.
/album/AbbeyRoad/song/0 returns { "come together", the beatles}

song/0 returns error: makes no sense without album

song/come_together returns [{"come together", aerosmith}, { "come together", the beatles}]

If you go with a required parent id design, then your backend needs the parent id to complete the operation.
If you go with a unique id design, you don't use the parent/child resource path at all as it just makes everyone life hard for no reason.

+1 Adding the parent to the route should be done when it adds value (i.e. providing a scope for the child's ID to make sense in), not just because of some arbitrary and irrelevant route structure.

@Ewan "Its part of the domain design whether the children only have meaning when linked to a parent, or if they are entities in their own right." but then you DO agree with my take: the fact that all children have unique IDs in the database is just a detail that is irrelevant to the domain. the domain always requires the parent ID to read the child, regardless of whether the child could be identified and fetched without the parent. the domain layer (and application layer) should not rely on this detail - which could change at any point.

@Flater thanks, so in your opinion this would be bad practice:
/authors/Dostojewski/isbn/9783423124102
(since isbn is unique anyway)

@PhilippMurry: it's pointless. However, if you look in the StackExchange URL, you get both the question ID and its title. The title is functionally irrelevant but is added for human eyes if they're looking at URLs. It's not pointless, but it has no technical justification and does not need to be validated as part of the fetch process.

@PhilippMurry So if you want to add it, you do you. But it has to have a benefit of some kind, because you have to consider that your consumer now will be suggested to supply more information than they need, which is an added cost.

I think the name is prob added for SEO rather than humans, Also it doesnt seem to be used, you can change it to anything

@Flater In my case, all Parents and Children have UUIDs, so I indeed could model every URL as a flat top-level endpoint. however, the relationship is definitely such that the Child couldn't survive without the Parent, so I thought providing the Child within a sub-resource is naturally expected by users. but maybe that was just a false impression. thanks for your input anyways.

@PhilippMurry I agree that its the domain decision that's important, not how its implemented. But not that the decision is an implementation detail. If you have had to make the decision to require the parent id, the factors that lead to that decision should make it impossible to accidentally add a unique id. eg song index in album

If your parent and childs all have unique ids, then it makes your interface worse to require both to retrieve a child

@Ewan but the fact that all DB entries have UUIDs was an arbitrary decision based on no specific requirement. so when I model the Application Layer in such a way that no parent needs to be provided to fetch a child, doesn't this feel off from a pure Domain Model perspective?

@PhilippMurry As far as URL route structure goes, "the relationship is definitely such that the Child couldn't survive without the Parent" and "Children have UUIDs" are direct contradictions. A UUID ensure that the child doesn't need its parent in order for it to be identifiable. I get the distinct feeling that you're muddying the waters on how you should design your API routes versus what may or may not be happening on the domain level inside your backend. Whether the child is a subaggregate of the parent in your domain is irrelevant for your API routes and its consumers.

@PhilippMurry: "so I thought providing the Child within a sub-resource is naturally expected by users" I'm going to offer the suggestion that users don't care about this; but that you (the dev) care about this because you are aware of the internal structure.

@PhilippMurry: Your last comment is, at its very core, breaking the layer boundaries and stating that one layer would need to be designed to be identical to the others. If that were the case, then you wouldn't have any separation. The point of separating the layers is to make it so that you can design each for their own reasons, which might be the same but it might not be (= choice). You already decided to use UUIDs in your API routes. I can't judge why, or whether that's correct. But on the premise that this is what you do, then it makes no sense to require a parent ID at the same time.

@PhilippMurry: Based on that last comment, I think the URL route issue that you posted here is uncovering a deeper misunderstanding about your backend architecture design that would warrant a separate question and deeper investigation in how you model and separate each layer in your backend service.

@PhilippMurry If you were able to give the children a UUID it calls into question the idea that the domain logic requires they be accessed by a parentId. It means the Id is not meaningful and wont have duplicates. Usually with a parent/child compound id, there is some concrete reason for it, ie the songId is its index in the album. The street name is not unique. etc

@Flater (and Ewan): I extended the question and provided more context, feel free to check it out: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/455023
