How to Model Parent-Child relationships outside of Aggregates
I am developing an application with many Parent-Child relationships which are leaving me with some modeling questions. Before I ask, let me give you some context:
No aggregates 
While I am trying to follow DDD principles, these relationships are seldom true aggregates because they form no real consistency boundaries. Modeling them as aggregates would only lead to inconvenience for the users (i.e. concurrent access errors).
True Parent-Child relationships 
Nevertheless, these are true Parent-Child relationships, since deletion of the Parent requires deletion of all Children because they cannot exist on their own. Also, users will want to read all Children of a Parent, which I think requires sub-resources like:
GET /parent/uuid/children
Unique IDs 
Another thing to mention is that all entities are identified via UUIDs, so technically all Children are globally uniquely identifiable. The reason behind this is that there are no good natural identifiers other than the names, which are cumbersome to use. UUIDs are convenient to generate (no sequence needed) and to use, therefore we decided to go with this option.
Now my questions are:

Are there any DDD-specific best practices on how to model Parent-Child relationships that are not aggregates, but also not mere associations where no part strictly depends on the other? Currently the references are only IDs on both sides.

How should I model these relationships in the REST API, given the fact that all children could be uniquely identified? Should I still go with the sub-resource strategy, or should I make them top-level, even though they need only be read in relation to a Parent?

In the Application Layer that exposes the entities (mostly 1:1 from the Domain Layer), should I require the Parent ID to be given in order to fetch a Child? This is a similar question as 2), just one layer below.


Feel free to ask away if anything is unclear.

can you tell us what the parent and child are in your case? I think the hard part to understand here is this "not an aggregate, but also a 'true child'"

the domain is a bit abstract and not real-world related, thats why I left it out. basically its about Deployments of Software Products. The parent would be a Product (or solution), and the children can be components (app server, web server), environments (dev, prod), properties, etc. All of them have no meaning outside the Product-context, but if I'd put them all in one aggregate, the consistency boundary would stretch across the whole app, which I wanted to avoid. also, notice there are no reasonable natural IDs, so UUIDs for everything came in handy.

The part this question is missing, based on the original question that spawned this second question, is what you think the benefit is from adding the parent ID; given that you've established that it's not technically necessary to provide it. Neither in the first nor the second question have you actually pointed that out, which makes me question whether you're doing it because you believe it is better, or because you blindly assume that it has to be done without even wondering why.

I'm also questioning the implied assertion that you are following DDD, but are choosing to model things not based on how DDD is described, but based on how many aggregates you expect your codebase to have (when it seems you would have too few to your liking if you followed the DDD guideline). That seems like the wrong metric.

What it boils down to is this: you want to follow specific guidelines (DDD, REST), you then knowingly deviate from their guideline based on it not being what you expect it to be, and then you're posting a question asking how to comply with the guideline. The straightforward answer is to stop deviating. Now, maybe there is a good reason to deviate, but you're refusing to actually elaborate on that point, instead asking us to believe your claim that it is justified and to accept your vague context. This hinders the ability to find the right answer to the question.

@Flater regarding my decision for not modeling children as aggregates, let me quote from the classic "Implementing DDD" by Vernon: "The team put a lot of weight on the words 'Products have' ..., which influence their initial attempt to design Aggregates for this domain. The big aggregate looked attractive, but it wasn't truly practical. Once the application was running ..., it began to regularly experience transactional failures." I specifically mentioned this problem in my question: "Modeling them as aggregates would only lead to inconvenience for the users (i.e. concurrent access errors)"

@Flater Therefore I cannot model all Children as part of one big Product-Aggregate, because basically 80% of entities would be inside this aggregate. See mentioned problem above. Regarding your criticism that I did not point out why it might be relevant to provide the parent ID in method calls: This is also false. I specifically stated in my first question that there are drawbacks to checking all IDs in the REST layer (= not forwarding them to the service). You can disagree with these drawbacks, but stating they were not mentioned lets me wonder if you are only skimming through my questions.

"Modeling them as aggregates would only lead to inconvenience for the users (i.e. concurrent access errors)" - that seems somewhat paradoxical as this is exactly the problem aggregates are supposed to address, which indicates to me that there's some misunderstanding on your part on how to model aggregates (not really your fault, as there's a lot of misinformation out there). Have you read the original DDD book by E. Evans ("the blue book") - specifically, on the motivation around aggregates and how to refine the design? (And not just, say, the "red book" by Vaughn Vernon?)

@FilipMilovanović I'm gonna lean out of the window and say that the misunderstanding is on your part. aggregates should only be used where consistency constraints over a set of entities are present. otherwise (like in my case) you're just making the users' life worse, because now two users cannot concurrently edit child A and child B of the same aggregate. if there is no reason to prohibit concurrent editing, don't do it.

Within the confines of a specific software company or team there are absolutely aggregates that can be defined which match the way that the particular team works. However it is difficult to find aggregates that generalize to all possible teams / possible work flows. This is why generic tooling for software engineering tends to focus on generic terms (branches, builds, environments, deployments, ...) each team is free to adapt both the term and tooling to their needs. I suspect you are struggling to find meaningful aggregates, because your domain is (necessarily) too generic.

I think its fine to avoid the aggregate, the question is why do you want to avoid get by unique id? what's the perceived benefit to the long multi parameter urls?

"now two users cannot concurrently edit child A and child B of the same aggregate" - so why are you modeling them as the same aggregate, then?

@FilipMilovanović because in my case, all Children have the same Parent. so if child A and B are part of their Parent's aggregate, they are part of the same aggregate. I cannot avoid this, that's why I ditched the whole aggregate idea.

@Ewan the short answer is: its already written in stone. we are dealing with living software here, I cannot change the REST API to such an extent anymore. the long answer: I thought sub-resources were the way to go in Parent-Child relationships according to REST standards. that's why I tried to wrap my head around on how to best model them in my scenario.

"that's why I ditched the whole aggregate idea" - that's fine (in fact DDD doesn't require you to use any of the tactical patterns, including aggregates, you can use a completely different set of modeling primitives - DDD is not about that). I'm just saying that some of the design considerations behind the process of decomposing the system into aggregates (including constraints such as being able to "concurrently edit child A and child B") are glossed over in many DDD discussions online, but are present the original DDD book; the ideas are probably transferable to your problem domain.

Ahh well that's kind of a different question. I love "Is it RESTful?" questions, they are like the free points of softwareengineering, but you can prob tell from my answer that I have a dim view of this kind of thing. REST doesn't really have a spec, its a vague idea with some crazy bits people ignore. I think these compound resource URLS are problematic, they get too long, they collide with other routes and they just dont work when you start getting more than 2 deep, or have any sort of complexity to your relationships or different query params.

If you are stuck with the design, I would put in the parent check and throw if its incorrect. Just to avoid gettgin the blame for errors or the appearance of a bug. But I would also add a simple Child/Id route and transition to it over time

In DDD if your relationship crosses an Aggregate Root boundary then its OK to have orphaned children.
The whole point of an aggregate root is to keep the relationship consistency. If you can't have that for some reason. say the data is external to your app, or its just too big or whatever then you have to accept an External Id.
If you accept an External Id then you accept the possibility of orphaned children.
Given the information you have told us in this and your other question, I would have.. (using ints to keep the example short)
Parent  //AR 1
{
   Id: 1234
   ChildIds [12,13,45,567]
   ...
{

Child  //AR 2
{
   Id
   ...
}

/GetParentByid?id=123  returns Parent
/GetChildbyId?id=123   returns Child
/GetChildrenByParentId=parentid=123  returns Child[]

This solves all your use cases with single parameter methods
I would NOT have
/GetChildByParentIdAndChildId?parentId=123&childId=123

Because this leads to more errors where the client gets the parentId wrong, or hasn't got the parentId it needs to make the call. Essentially you make the real childId a composite key of parentId + childId
I would only use a composite key where the domain logic makes it sensible to do so. for example
GetDeliveryAddress(PostCode, HouseNumber)

I don't have a unique record for every address in the country, but I know a unique address is defined by this combination. PostCode relates to a collection of Addresses and House Number isn't unique. I can't make a unique key for every address because I don't have a list of them all.
It's the nature of the Domain that forces the composite key.
Edit
In your case of software deployments you can imagine a similar situation, say
GetDeployments(Product = "myApi", Env = "Test")

Where "myApi" and "Test" are natural, but non unique keys. But I would still expect a unique Id for Deployment, which would continue to exists as a historical record even if the product or env is deleted.
This might be preferable than generating a UUID for each environment and product, or enforcing unique Env keys across products.
But if you did make that choice
getDeployments(Env = "Test")

Just doesn't make sense in the domain, because there are dozens of "Test" envs with no relationship. The Domain choice you made, to use natural keys rather than a unique Id, effectively made the method parameter choice for you.

The routes mentioned in this answer are not REST-compliant as they're not referring to resources, e.g. "GetParentByid". I'm not saying that the API has to be purist REST, but method-like URLs play by different rules than REST URLs, which sidesteps question 2 instead of answering it.

How would you model the Environment endpoint? currently its: /products/123/environments/234. and in the Controller: environmentService.read(234); (notice that the '123' is the problem in question). For retrieving a list its: /products/123/environments

if its a uniqueId I would do /GetEnvironment?id=123 if its a compound key I would do /getEnvironment?ProductId=123&EnvironmentId=Test fully compatible with REST and avoiding route collisions with string ids

I don't understand why you are wedded to this format of a url with two parameters? What do you think the benefit is?

@PhilippMurry This previous comment is really what it boils down to, sidestepping all the DDD and REST talk. You keep trying to stand up for the two parameter approach, but offer no reasoning as to what the actual benefit is, and are repeatedly ignoring that it's irrelevant to do so. Put it this way: for the consumer, it's a net negative (needing to supply more info for no reason). For the service, it's irrelevant (ignores the given value). Cui bono? Who is this benefiting? The only sensible remaining explanation is that it's what the dev wants. But wants with net negative impacts are bad.
